# Is there any way to debug PHP application running in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any way to debug PHP application running in Google App Engine, similar that you can do in your localhost? For example with PhpStorm like this (this is localhost example): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE in section 6.

I am running with a issue using PDO Mysql adapter in ZF2 application running on my Google App Engine and I do not get any errors, except that request timeouts. On my local Google App engine server PDO Mysql adapter works fine.

Comment: Not like you can locally. Appengine has a new cloud traces feature look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine doesn't currently support any type of remote debugging for PHP applications, although currently it is possible to perform live production debugging of Java applications on Managed VMs.

https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/

Comment: Thank you Andrew, even though the news were not as happy as I would expect :)